# Get the CPU temperature from a raspberry pi to the Watson IoT Platform quickstart service

Tags: node.js, linux, raspberry-pi, watson-iot

I need to get the CPU temperature from a raspberry pi to the Watson IoT Platform quickstart service.

I am doing this by using an exec node in node red with the command `vcgencmd measure_temp`. I want to send this temperature value as a number to the **Watson IOT** node but my exec node returns the CPU temperature as "`temp=45.2C`". I tried using the solution that is provided on the forum

```
msg.payload={"temp":msg.payload.replace("temp=","").replace("'C\n","")};
```

but when I submit the solution, the grader still treat the O/P as String rather than a number, **what should I do to turn the `msg.payload O/P` as a number?**

Comment: What grader? Is this homework?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Questions on course homework/assignments should be asked in the course's forums.

Answer (score 4):

I bet you are doing the Coursera course.

Perhaps you haven't `converted(parse)` the string?? The command `replace()` you did is to strip unnecessary `string`, and in fact it is still `string`.

So you can consider using either `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` for the remaining "`45.2`".

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp